# Deployment to Google’s Compute Engine fails: Error retrieving the App Engine service account

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

After **I’ve deleted some values** (do not remember which) in my project configuration (in the *Developer Console*) I cannot deploy an app to a *Compute Engine* instance. I’ve deployed the same code using the same configuration dozens of times successfully but after deleting some values in the Developer Console or doing some other adjustments that I considered minor, the deployment, using Maven plugin v2.0.9.95.v20160203, fails with

```
[INFO] Beginning deployment...
[INFO] WARNING: If this is your first deployment, please try again.
[INFO] ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
[INFO]   Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
[INFO]   Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~some-id'). Error retrieving the App Engine service account. 
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app command with exit code : 1
```

I run

```
mvn clean validate gcloud:deploy
```

Unlike in some other of my projects I do not have both of the accounts

1. App Engine default service account - some-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
2. Compute Engine default service account - some-id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

…in my **Permissions** section but only the 2. account.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you deleted your App Engine service account. To create it again, you can go to the [Permissions section](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions/) of your project and add a new member with the email YOUR-PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com (replace with your real project id) and "Can Edit" permissions.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve added this info to the original problem description. Still I cannot add a *some-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com* account there.

I can only add an account with a *@some-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com* suffix. The suffix is fixed and cannot be adjusted.

Comment: You are trying to create it as a service account. Try to add it as a new member.

Comment: I’ve tried to add *some-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com* as a new member instead and I’ve got ”An email address does not belong to an active account”

Comment: This was working a couple of weeks ago. They must have updated the Developer Console. There should be an alternative way of restoring the App Engine service account, try to find if it is possible with gcloud.

Comment: I’ve tried out the alpha & beta versions of gcloud. I think “backend-services” … apparently “users” and “add-member” were not the correct commands… However, I am going to create a completely new project from scratch and need to adjust the IDs and URLs… :( Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Im also looking for a way to create  some-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as I've accidentally deleted it. Cant see this option in the console though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not authenticated to your project anymore? Have you tried to reauthenticate using `gcloud auth login`?

If you're authenticated but happen somehow to delete default Google AppEngine service account (app_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), you won't be able to recreate them yourself. You will need to file a support ticket with Google and ask them to recreate the default service account for you.

Finally, you can create new project and deploy your application there but of course this comes at a price/time.

Comment: Yes, I did this as well but AFAIK the Maven plugin (should) takes care of the authentication separately.