# Unable to create cluster on Dataproc after deleting default service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I had mistakenly deleted a default "service account" for my project - {project_id}-**compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com**
Now whenever I try to create a cluster on Data proc I get the following error:

> The resource '{project_id}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.

Is there an easy way to resolve this issue - without losing any data for the project.

Comment: Just curious, did you delete the service account through the web UI or using a command-line tool? The web UI tries to warn against deleting the account and requires typing in the entire account name to verify rather than just a simple confirmation prompt because it can be tedious to fix as shown in my answer below (though I understand sometimes skimming over melodramatic warnings especially if it's not obvious exactly what it breaks :) - if there are any official Google tools which make it too easy to break your project like that we'll want to add extra protections for it in the future.

Comment: @DennisHuo thank you so much for the detailed response. I deleted the account through the web UI. Also, I think it'd be better if only a "project owner" has the rights to perform such action. Currently an "editor" can delete as well.

Comment: @DennisHuo would you by any chance also know how to restore the default "app engine service account" as well :P

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I believe since the App Engine enablement is tied to project creation and not API enablement, it wouldn't be as easy as disabling/re-enabling in the API manager. If you have a support contract you could try contacting official support teams to see if they can reinstate the service account from the inside; otherwise you might have better luck posting a new question specifically about the @appspot.gserviceaccount.com app engine service account under [google-app-engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) to get more app engine-specific info.

Comment: Looks like others have encountered a similar problem of accidental deletion before, and some of the answers also initially confused it with simply deleting it from the list of project members, as opposed to deleting the account itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316238/deployment-to-google-s-compute-engine-fails-error-retrieving-the-app-engine-ser

Comment: @DennisHuo Thank you for the details! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify to anyone else who encounters this issue, this error is caused by actually deleting the service account, and not simply from removing it from the list of "project editors" under the `IAM and Admin` options; to anyone who only removed the account from the project editor list, you can simply add it back using the normal "Add Member".

Generally the service account gets created at the time the Compute Engine API is enabled, so at the moment it works to fix this issue simply by disabling and then re-enabling the Compute Engine API through the [API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/enabled).

This could cause problems if you already have existing Compute Engine VMs running which you depend on for your production capabilities, but if you deleted the service account, then those VMs are likely somewhat broken anyways.

Find `Google Compute Engine API` there and click on "disable", and make sure to click the `Disable` button on the confirmation prompt instead of the `Cancel` button.

When re-enabling the Compute Engine API, you may encounter the following error:

```
Update failed with following error(s) for project settings: -- Backend Provisioning Error: {compute_component FAILED_PRECONDITION: The service is currently being deactivated and deactivation must complete before activation can occur.};
```

but if you wait a couple minutes and try again, it should work (I waited about 3 minutes before trying again, but the required wait may vary). Likewise, at first after re-enabling the Compute API and immediately trying to create a new Dataproc cluster, you may hit:

```
Failed to load networks

Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project <project-number> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/overview?project=<project-number> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

But as it mentions, again waiting a couple minutes lets the settings propagate and it should load fine again.

Once the Compute Engine API is re-enabled sufficiently that Dataproc's `Create Cluster` page works on the cloud console, you can also verify again under `IAM and Admin` that the default compute service account exists again and that it has been auto-added as a `Project editor` as well.