# Google Cloud (GCE) doesn't have access to default service account while creating VM instance

Tags: gcloud, google-compute-engine

Looks like there's a bug.
Following official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance

After

```
gcloud compute instances create test-2
```

Recieved:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource '1045904521672-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found.
```

Being authorized correctly, role is set to Owner.

```
> gcloud auth list
```

returns

```
      Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       **@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

However, an instance can be created with custom service account.
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to: [Unable to create cluster on Dataproc after deleting default service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896614/unable-to-create-cluster-on-dataproc-after-deleting-default-service-account)

Perhaps the answers there can help you out.